# How to Make geo.SearchRegion Transient

Tags: bixby

I am trying to write a capsule that will ask the user for a `geo.SearchRegion` and give them the opportunity to search again after they have results.

The issue is that I need to train the language model on `geo.LocalityName` (to get a city name). I have created my own alias of that:

```
name (LocalityName) {
  description (alias of geo.LocalityName)
  extends (geo.LocalityName)
  features {
    transient
  }
}
```

which works fine. The problem is that when I do the same with `geo.SearchRegion` I lose the built in ability to match a `LocalityName` to a `SearchRegion`.

```
structure (SearchRegion) {
  description (alias of geo.SearchRegion)
  extends (geo.SearchRegion)
  features {
    transient
  }
}
```

So when I have the following Evaluate action:

```
action (Evaluate) {
  description (Find the value)
  type (Search)
  collect {
    input (type) {
      type (StatsType)
      min (Required) max (One)
      default-init {
        intent {
          goal: GetAllTypes
        } 
      }
    }
    input-group (location) {
      requires (OneOf)
      collect {
        input (searchRegion) {
          type (geo.SearchRegion)
          min (Optional) max (One)
          default-select {
            with-learning
            with-rule {
              select-first
            }
          }
        }
        input (postalCode) {
          type (PostalCode)
          min (Optional) max (One)
          default-select {
            with-learning
            with-rule {
              select-first
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  output (Result)
}
```

It works, but will not allow me to re-do the search. When I change `geo.SearchRegion` to `SearchRegion` it no longer works, since it can't match the locality name.

What should I do to enable the user to search again?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend changing that input to a computed-input ([Documentation](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/action.collect.computed-input)) in the action and define its prompt behavior as prompt-behavior(AlwaysElicitation). This will result in Bixby requesting the user for a location every time.